# UIView animation annomily

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer

I am currently trying to animation from one view to another using a swipe gesture which in turn would animate View A off the screen to the left and then have view B animate along with it by appear from the right.

This is actually working in my application however when the views animate instead of View B following on the edge of View A and have them both move at the same time, View B will not move untill View A's animatoin has finished...

this is what the code looks like

```
- (void)swipedScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 animations:^{

//            [self.detailViewB.view setAlpha:1.0f];
            [self.detailViewB.view setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame))];
            [self.detailViewA.view setCenter:CGPointMake(-640, CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame))]; 
        }];
    }
}
```

And if you would like to compile the source yourself here is a link to the code I am messing around with.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53813770/SMPrototypeB.zip

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to put them in separate animation blocks, or different calls to `animateWithDuration:animations:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your code and reuploaded the project [here](http://cl.ly/Gzaa)

Changes I made:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self.detailViewB.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

}


- (void)swipedScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 animations:^{

            //            [self.detailViewB.view setAlpha:1.0f];
            [self.detailViewB.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            [self.detailViewA.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: worked perfectly.. just going through the code now to understand it abit better. :) cheers man!

Comment: no problem! glad you got it working. I'm just setting detailB to 320 (off the screen to the right) and animating detailA -320 (off the screen left) and animating detailB to 0(viewable)

Comment: ahhh.. I see.. very cool, done so much apple docs reading today I just couldn't get it :P